# A simple stack implementation using C

Tags: c

I had written a program in C to implement a simple stack. But I am getting segmentation fault in my program and finding it hard to find out what is wrong. Can any one help,

```
   #include<stdio.h>
   #include<stdlib.h>
   struct stack_structure{
     int stack_array[10];
     int stack_pointer;
   };
   void push_into_stack(struct stack_structure *,int);
   int main(){
     int no = 8;
     struct stack_structure *st;
     st->stack_pointer = -1;
     push_into_stack(st,no);
     return 0;
   }
   void push_into_stack(struct stack_structure *s,int no){
     s -> stack_pointer++;
     s -> stack_array[s -> stack_pointer] = no;
   }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
struct stack_structure *st;
```

This only creates a pointer to a `struct stack_structure`. It does not allocate memory for the  `struct stack_structure` itself.

You can try with this:

```
struct stack_structure st;
st.stack_pointer = -1;
push_into_stack(&st,no);
```

The other option is to dynamically allocate (and free) that structure:

```
struct stack_structure *st = malloc(sizeof(struct stack_structure));
...
// when you're done with it
free(st);
```

Answer (score 4):

See these lines:

```
 struct stack_structure *st;
 st->stack_pointer = -1;
```

You've declared a pointer variable but then you're using it uninitialized. A pointer has to point at something, and this one doesn't have anything to point to. The simplest fix would be to change these lines to:

```
 struct stack_structure st1, *st=&st1;
 st->stack_pointer = -1;
```

Comment: What about passing this struct varible into push_into_stack() function. &st1 should be passed?

Comment: I kept the pointer variable `st` you had, but gave it something to point out, in order to minimize the changes needed to fix your code. Of course it's better not to even make a pointer variable if you don't need it and just use `&` when you need to take the address of the structure to pass it to another function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to malloc some space for the structure:

```
struct stack_structure *st = malloc(sizeof(struct stack_structure));
```